# Nutch: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback

Tags: java, spring, indexing, nutch

I am running the normal Nutch indexing, it used to work 2 days ago perfectly but today out of nowhere it just stopped working with the previous error. Following the stack error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:161)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.<init>(IndexWriters.java:55)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:121)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:238)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.retry.RetryCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

I ended up seeing that the error occurred at this exact piece of code :

```
Object object = extensionClazz.newInstance();
```

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631770/spring-amqp-has-noclassdeffounderror-in-springframework-retrycallback-class) on SO but with different project was able to fix the issue by adding the spring-framework-messaging dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

well i am using nutch version 1.12 with ivy for dependency management so in my config is the following:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework.retry" name="spring-retry" rev="1.2.0.RELEASE">
      <exclude module="spring-beans"/>
      <exclude module="spring-context"/>
      <exclude module="spring-core"/>
      <exclude module="spring-aop"/>
</dependency>
```

and even with adding the spring-messaging dependency it's still not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the output of 
"mvn dependency:tree " command in your project.

Comment: @Timothy i am using ivy as mentioned not mvn, and running ant runtime have no errors

Comment: Ok , Can you execute the ivy report 
by including the below ant task in your ivy config files?
<report conf="compile" />
What I suspect is that this jar is being imported by more than one source and hence there is a conflict

Comment: i can't find where to add the report tag tried everywhere but still getting an error  unknown tag report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what went wrong but this was able to fix the problem

```
ant clean
ant runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of errors might come when you have more than one version of same jar (same class) in your classpath, You can see the dependency tree by executing

```
<report conf="compile" /> for ivy projects
```

And

```
mvn dependency:tree for maven projects
```

Narrow down to the version that you want and you can exclude the other  jar by explicitly excluding that jar from the module which is importing it .

Comment: after adding it to build.xml reports where not generated, this is how i added the report 
<target name="report" depends="resolve-test" description="--> generates a report of dependencies">
    <ivy:report conf="compile" todir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>